# Is there a way to pre-specify multiple initial Markov states when using rmarkovchain in the marckovchain library?

Tags: r, markov-chains, stochastic-process

I'm using rmarkovchain from library("markovchain").

In this function we have the option to specify time 0.

For example:

```
rmarkovchain(n = 10,                  #number of time moments eg. 10 days
             object = dtmcA, 
             t0 = "event0",           #here time 0
             include.t0 = TRUE,       #here time 0
             parallel = TRUE)
```

However, I want to specify the first three days (in example time is in days) i.e. `t0`, `t1`, `t2` as `[event0,event0,event0]`.

In other words the first 3 days will be event0.

For this example there are a total of three potential events:
`event 0, event 1, event 2`

And the transition matrix can be anything, for example:

```
   0   1  2
0 0.3 0.2 0.5
1 0.1 0.7 0.2 
2 0    0   1
```

Can this be done using rmarkovchain?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I've found a few approaches reading the documentation and published literature, but the one which worked best for me was the `noofVisitsDist` function in the markovchain library.

Posting in case anyone else runs into a similar question.

Sincerely.